# have been trying to use loop through a form

Tags: php, laravel

it keeps giving me two dropdowns instead of just one with multiple data called from database

```
@foreach ($leave_t as $leaveType)
{{ Form::select('leaveType', array('LeaveType' => 'Select Leave Type', $leaveType->leave_type), '', ['class' => 'form-control m-b']) }}
@endforeach
```

in my controller

```
$leaveType = leaveType::all();
        return view('leave.application')->with('leave_t', $leaveType);
```

Comment: because you are creating multiple selects ... every time that loop iterates you are creating a new select box with `Form::select`

Comment: @lagbox please how do i loop through without creating multiple select?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: you don't loop at all ... what is `$leave_t` where did you get it ... what are these values?

Comment: @Rigel i want the dropdown to select some data fetched from the database

Comment: include the code in your question that gets you `$leave_t`

Comment: @NICANDIAS check my answer.

Comment: have added the controller in my question @lagbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a list that is keyed by the 'id' and has something like the 'name' as the value (what is displayed as the option):

```
$leaveType = leaveType::pluck('leave_type', 'id');
```

Then in your form you can use this list for the select:

```
Form::select(
    'leaveType',
     ['' => 'Select Leave Type'] + $leave_t->all(),
     '',
     ['class' => 'form-control m-b']
)
```

Now you will have a select with options who's values are the 'id's of the leaveTypes and 'leave_type' is used for display of the option.

Comment: i noticed that the dromdown is displaying the list of leave type in the dats base but when i want to save the form its saving the id not the leaveType

Comment: Thanks, have gotten the desired output

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `@foreach` and replace your select with this.

```
{{ Form::select('leaveType', $leave_t, '', ['class' => 'form-control m-b']) }}
```

**In your controller**

```
$leaveTypes = $leaveType->prepend(['LeaveType' => 'Select Leave Type'])->pluck('leave_t', 'id');
return view('leave.application')->with('leave_t', $leaveTypes);
```

Comment: This what what i got as the output ["Annual","study"], its correct but Annual is suppose to be an option to be selected and Study should be another option

Comment: `id` is the `primary key` of `leaveType`